# Unit testing: Input/output

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to run a unit test for the following code: This code below only checks if the function is true.

Here is the Unit testing code:

```
  import {encodeLengthHex, toHex } from './utils';

// testing new function 
describe('EncodeLengthHex', () => {   //mocking the method
test('Testing Function toHex ', () => { // declaring the method
const str = 128 // initial value
const actual = encodeLengthHex(str) // calculate the value
expect(actual).toMatchSnapshot(); // checking whether is true
})
});
```

Here is the main code:

```
 export function encodeLengthHex(n) {
if (n <= 127) {
  return toHex(n);
}
const nHex = toHex(n);
const lengthOfLengthByte = 128 + nHex.length / 2;
  return toHex(lengthOfLengthByte) + nHex;
```

Function is passing. But how could I add a few inputs to test and compare when this function pass or fail. Thanks

Comment: This is caused by a spelling mistake: instead of encodeLenghtHex, it should be encodeLengthHex. In the module under test, you're spelling it right, in the test, you're spelling it wrong

Comment: I didn't even see that. I updated the code here. But I still getting an error.     expect(received)[.not].toBeLessThan(expected)

    Received value must be a number.
    Received:
      string: "08"

Comment: Well, you are passing in a string in your test, while the function under test seems to expect a number…

Comment: I understand that, but its weird because I have a similar test, which I pass a string and its running fine

Comment: [toBeLessThan](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobelessthannumber) expects a number as argument, if it doesn't get one, it throws an error. Your `encodeLengthHex` function returns a string if it gets a string argument, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I have to work on toHex function as well